# Characters that map to an odd number of bytes using Encoding.Unicode

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, encoding

I know in some situations, some characters will take up more space when using `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()`. For example:

`var value = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("");`, for which `value.Length` is 4.

This is different from:

`var value = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("a");`, for which `value.Length` is 2.

However, I am really curious about something. Is it possible to come up with a set of characters that will cause `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes()` to return an odd number of bytes, perhaps using combining characters or some other way? If so, could someone please show me one such example? If not, why is that?

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` is a UTF-16LE encoding. The code unit is a 16-bit value.

Comment: There are Unicode encodings that can have odd number of bytes (the obvious example is UTF8, where simple Roman characters (like 'a') take up one byte, and there are many three-byte characters). The Unicode entry on Wikipedia has a pretty good overview of Unicode and its encodings

Comment: @RaymondChen The Old New Thing :) Thanks, Raymond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#cite_note-Unicode7Ch3s8-5), characters in these ranges have the following byte size:

U+0000 to U+D7FF: 2 bytes.

U+E000 to U+FFFF: 2 bytes.

U+D800 to U+DFFF: Reserved to distinguish surrogate pairs (see below) and should not encode, but, despite the official Unicode standard saying that no UTF forms, including UTF-16, can encode these code points, it still works in C#: `var value = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("\uD800");` Also note that converting these values back using `var str = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(value);` does not give you the same result!

U+10000 to U+10FFFF: 4 byte characters, with two 2 byte surrogate pairs that make use of the above reserved range. **SPECIAL NOTE**: Although  is one character, it is actually stored as two characters in C# strings. The following is true: `Debug.Assert("".Length == 2);` Be careful!

U+110000 and above: Should not encode, and also seem to not encode in C#. For example, this does not work: `var str = "\U00110000";`

If we assume that any given character takes up 2 or 4 bytes respectively (which I am still not sure of at this point because of how the encoder behaves), then it follows by simple math proof that two even numbers divided by two are still even. Even numbers are multiples of 2, written as: `2m + 2n`

The above formula is always evenly divisible by two, as `(2m + 2n) / 2` = `m + n`.

Comment: `"\U000110000"` is actually `"\U00011000"` (U+11000) followed by `"0"` (U+0030). `\U` is limited to 8 digits max. U+11000 is in the valid codepoint range for UTF-16.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I modified my answer. I had an extra 0. It seems to not encode beyond the valid Unicode range. I say seems because I haven’t tried all possible combinations of 8 character hex code points.

Comment: UTF-16 is physically limited to codepoint U+10FFFF max. It simply cannot encode higher codepoint values. If `Encoding.Unicode` accepts higher codepoints without error, then it has a bug that should be reported to Microsoft.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But why do reserved characters (U+D800 to U+DFFF) encode when they’re by themselves?

Comment: Because they are still valid codepoints in the U+0000..U+10FFFF range that UTF-16 can handle. They are simply *reserved* codepoints that should *never* be used in *unencoded* form when processing codepoints in strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be slightly mislead on codepoints and number of bytes, or how the characters can be combined to create a string. There are `2**16` codepoints, you could conceivably enumerate each codepoint to get the value and return the bytes if you wanted confirmation.

Unicode has "planes" to describe characters (for the sake of this question assume UTF-16, as these ranges change with UTF-8 and UTF-32). Specific combinations of bytes create "pairs", which while they still represent one character, actually take up 4 bytes to describe.

In UTF-16, these are the characters with a codepoint value higher than `0x00FFFF`, which are all 4 bytes, while anything equal or less will use 2 bytes. As I already stated, this only holds true for UTF-16.

So while the number of bytes may be slightly variable (though predictably so), the values will always be even as, they will either be 2 or 4.

Comment: Do we agree that  is one character?

Comment: Yes, one "character" that that takes 4 bytes to describe due to the "planes" Unicode uses. Any character that has a code point value higher than `0x00FFFF` is going to be 4 bytes. Everything less is going to be 2 bytes. This is assuming we are still talking about UTF-16. This can change with UTF-8 and and UTF-32.

Comment: I think you should consider updating the wording in your answer to include surrogate pairs, for characters which may encode to 4 bytes.

Comment: You are confusing code points (U+000000 to U+10FFFF) and code units (unit of storage: for UTF-16, it's a 16-bit value).